# updating the state in componentWillMount

Tags: react-native

i want to create a object with multiple object. the data is something like this

`dataList = [{inputFieldId: 1, dataField:{...}, data: '120'}, {inputFieldId: 2, dataField:{...}, data: '120'} ]`

what is want like this.

`res = [{1: '120'}, {2: '120'}]`

i write a code for this but its giving me the last object data only.

```
  constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
  inputValue:{},
  datalist = [],
  }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.state.inputValue)
  this.props.navigation.setParams({ sendDataToServer: 
 this._sendDataToServer });
 }

   async componentWillMount(){
     for(var key in dataList){
        this.setState({
           inputValue: {
             ...this.state.inputValue,
             [dataList[key].inputFieldId]: dataList[key].data
          }
      })
  }     
}
```

`code output = { 2: '120'}`

thanks in advance

Comment: If your data was initialized tin the state , you can get your output in the render method

Comment: array--> {2: "120"}

Answer (score 0):

`setState` work asynchronously. Instead of this

```
this.setState({
  inputValue: {
    ...this.state.inputValue,
    [dataList[key].inputFieldId]: dataList[key].data
  }
})
```

Try to change to this

```
this.setState((previousState) => ({
  inputValue: {
    ...previousState.inputValue,
    [dataList[key].inputFieldId]: dataList[key].data
  }
}))
```